# Why do you need parenthesis to save the result of a regular expression in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Why does this return the string between foo and bar:

`my ($var) = $my_string =~ /foo(.*)bar/;`

And this return the number 1 if there is a hit and nothing if there is no match:

`my $var = $my_string =~ /foo(.*)bar/;`

Specifically what are the parenthesis around the variable doing?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context

Comment: Note: You could also use a list slice: `my $var = ( $my_string =~/foo(.*)bar/ )[0];`

Comment: Or `my $var = $my_string =~/foo(.*)bar/ ? $1 : undef;`. The advantage of `my ($var)` is that you can easily add error handling: do `my ($var) = /foo/ or die;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with many things in Perl, the result of that expression is different based on the context that is put in.

The pattern match operator will return a list of captures in list contact (your first example). If the operator is evaluated in scalar context (your second example), a boolean is indicating whether it matched or not is returned instead.

To answer your specific question, placing parens around `$var` forces it into list context and assigns the first element of the list returned from the pattern match to `$var`.

This is effectively the same as these statements:

```
my @matches = $my_string =~ /foo(.*)bar/;
my $var = $matches[0];
```

Comment: It's been fixed, but `=~` is not the match operator, and more importantly, a list isn't returned in scalar context.

Comment: It said if the list is placed in scalar context, its size is returned. How is that me saying a list is returned ?

Comment: I think you should look at the post before the edit again. It says no such thing.

Comment: You said that a list was returned, and that it could be placed in scalar context. ("The pattern match operator =~ will return a list of captures. If that list is placed in list context, ...") Wrong on both counts. No list was returned, and it's impossible to place that kind of list in scalar context. You can only place *operators* in scalar context, not values or a list of values.

Comment: "forces it into list context" isn't clear; parens around `$var` makes it *syntactically* a list assignment, which gives its right operand list context

Answer (score 1):

Because the regex match operator returns a list, and you must provide a list context if you want the list values.  In the parentheses case you provide a list context, so the variable gets set... but only the first value returned would be saved.  If your regex returned multiple sub-matches you'd need to provide more than one variable, as in:

```
($a,$b) = $string =~ /\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/;
```

In the bare (non-parentheses) case, you provide scalar context, and the match operator in scalar context returns a boolean indicating whether the pattern matched or not.

Answer (score 1):

Because in first case you are doing regex matching in list context and http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html says in that case:

> In list context, a match /regex/ with groupings will return the list of matched values ($1,$2,...)

In second case, regex return true (1)